# adding products with custom options to order in admin

Tags: custom-options

I am having a bug in which when I try adding products with custom options (mageworx plugin) to order in admin if I select and configure more than one product and then press  the 'Add Selected Product(s) to Order' button only the first product keeps all the selected options and built out SKU (from custom options)the rest of the selected products just have plain SKU and no custom options selected is this a bug how can i fix?
in `js\mage\adminhtml\sales.js` i see `productConfigure.submit(listType);` is what is being called to update order but i have no dea were that function is to try to look what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yehuda!

Looks like you are either using some outdated version or there's some conflict with other extensions.

Please contact our support team (mageworx.com/support) and we'll fix it.